# Error "No such file or directory" when running Django ./manage.py

Tags: python, django, bash, virtualenv

In my `django` project, the command `./manage.py [command]` results in this error message:

```
: No such file or directory
```

The command `python manage.py [command]` works well. I tried with `syncdb` and `runserver`.
I tried `chmod a+x manage.py`, but the problem persists.

My manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I use django 1.4.1 in a `virtualenv`.
How can I fix this to use `manage.py [command]`?

Comment: are you sure you are in the right directory?

Comment: What does `/usr/bin/env python` give you when entered into the terminal?

Comment: I'm sure, @Snakes. `python manage.py [command]` wouldn't work in a wrong directory ;-)

Comment: Ever find a solution for this Marcos? I'm having the same exact problem with the same manage.py. Weird this is I have an almost identical project, and it works fine.

Answer (score 10):

Likely, the reason is because your line endings in the manage.py file are \n instead of \r\n. As a result the #! hash-bang is misinterpreted.

This happens to me when I use a Windows based text-editor for my linux connection.

Comment: I found this if I let git on windows checkout with autoclrf true and then use the files in vagrant. If you plan on a vagrant environment - use the autoclrf "input" mode.

Answer (score 6):

The `#!` hash-bang line doesn't point to your virtualenv python; replace the first line with:

```
#!/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python
```

Answer (score 3):

> In my django project, the command ./manage.py [command] results in
>   this error message:
>
> : No such file or directory
>
> The command python manage.py [command] works well

If specifying the interpreter makes it work, then it is the first line that must be wrong:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

(or wherever the interpreter is. Find it with: `which python`).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was erroneously changing the `sys.path` in my `manage.py`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case on Windows 7, every else it seems to be, but I've accidentally added an import in a views.py file:

```
from Scripts.pilprint import description
```

My software doesn't need this import, maybe with some wrong short-kut, my Eclipse wrote it for me, but removed this line, the problem disappear.

I suppose that description contain some painful character or have a wrong encoding for Windows.